# Insertion Sort Algorithm Off by One Error

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting

My Python code for the Insertion Sort Algorithm nearly works, but for some reason the first item of my list is not sorted - could someone please tell me where the problem is?

```
listToBeSorted = [7,2,4,3,6,5,1]
for pointer in range(1, len(listToBeSorted )):
    itemToBeInserted = listToBeSorted[pointer]
    currentIndex = pointer - 1
    while listToBeSorted[currentIndex] > itemToBeInserted and currentIndex > 0:
       listToBeSorted[currentIndex + 1] = listToBeSorted[currentIndex]
       currentIndex -= 1
    listToBeSorted[currentIndex + 1] = itemToBeInserted

print(listToBeSorted)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code ends the `while` loop too early. Instead of `currentIndex > 0`, you want `currentIndex >= 0`, so that you can shift the first value in the list forwards if necessary.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is at this statement

```
while listToBeSorted[currentIndex] > itemToBeInserted and currentIndex > 0
```

which should be

```
while listToBeSorted[currentIndex] > itemToBeInserted and currentIndex > -1
```

If `currentIndex` always larger than 0, then the first element of the list never get sorted because no item in the list would be inserted at the beginning of the list.

```
listToBeSorted = [7,2,4,3,6,5,1]
for pointer in range(1, len(listToBeSorted )):
    itemToBeInserted = listToBeSorted[pointer]
    currentIndex = pointer - 1
    while listToBeSorted[currentIndex] > itemToBeInserted and currentIndex > -1:
       listToBeSorted[currentIndex + 1] = listToBeSorted[currentIndex]
       currentIndex -= 1
    listToBeSorted[currentIndex + 1] = itemToBeInserted

print(listToBeSorted)
```